# In Mark 3, is it Jesus' family or friends who try to take him away

Tags: greek, jesus, mark

Mark 3:21 NLT "When his family heard what was happening, they tried to take him away. “He’s out of his mind,” they said."

IN other versions it says "own people" or "friends"

The greek was not very clear to me; it looks like an interpretation question rather than translation. Can anyone elaborate on which group is correct.

It seems to me that there are some strong implication between this verse and verse 33 Jesus replied, “Who is my mother? Who are my brothers?” assuming that the first reference is to family.

Comment: Nice question and welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  We are glad you stopped by and hope you stay. If you haven't done so already, you may want to read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than others. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read in isolation the text does not tell us clearly whether those who came and said "He is beside himself" were friends or family. However, the context gives a possible answer, because Mark 3:20-21, Mark 3:22-30, Mark 3:31-35 form an intercalation or *sandwich* (A1-B-A2). This is listed by John Dominic Crossan in *[The Birth of Christianity](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/76888.The_Birth_of_Christianity)*, page 106, as among the six Markan intercalations  most widely recognised by New Testament scholars.

A Markan intercalation is a literary device the author uses for mutual emphasis of two otherwise unrelated issues. The first issue begins with the claim that Jesus had lost his senses (A1), followed by the scribes saying that Jesus was in league with the devil (B), then Jesus rejecting his family, saying that, for him, his followers were now his mother and brethren (A2). Family ties were strong, so Mark needed a compelling reason to say that Jesus would reject his family, and their prior rejection of him provides that reason.

This sandwich matches the people who came and said "He is beside himself" (Mark 3:20-21, event A1) with his brethren and his mother (Mark 3:31-35, event A2), providing evidence that the people in Mark 3:21 were actually Jesus' family.

Comment: Thanks Dick, I'm going to track down a copy of the book.

Answer (score 1):

The Bauer, Arndt, Gingrich *Lexicon* says that, in addition to "someone's envoys", "the Koine also uses this expression to denote others who are intimately connected w. someone, e.g. family, relatives". [p.615]

So it could mean Jesus' family, immediate or extended, or his disciples.  The latter is doubtful.  I agree with you, that this is a matter of interpretation, not translation.  And I think "his own people" is a nearer (more literal) translation than "his family".

I also agree that he responded as he did in v.33 because it was, at that time, his own family who calling on him. Were these the same folks in v.21?  very sermon material IMO, since he concludes by testing his relationship with a man by that man's obedience to the will of God.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange, we are glad you are here.  When you have a chance, be sure to check out the [site tour](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) and read up on  how this site is [a little different](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives#803) than other sites around the web. *This is not a comment on the quality of your answer, but rather a standard welcome message.*

Answer (score 0):

The question "In Mark 3 is it Jesus' family or friends who try to take him away" presupposes that the Greek text currently accepted is what Mark actually wrote. But if, as I hope to show below, it is not, it does no one any service to continue to believe that Mark actually wrote this strange material and not the perfect sense he actually wrote. The Greek text currently accepted reads 20 Erchetai eis oikon kai sunerchetai palin o ochlos oste me dunasthai autous mede arton phagein 21 kai akousantes oi par' autou exelthon kratesai auton. Elegon gar oti exeste (20 He went into his house and the crowd came together again so as not to be able to eat 21 and those around him, hearing, went out to seize him. They said he was mad). The sense is peculiar: (1) If he was in his house, how could those around him (natural meaning "those with him in his house") go out of the house where he was in order to find him somewhere else to seize him? (2) It defies belief that Mark could have written that those around him could have believed he was mad when he has given no evidence whatever which could possibly support such a belief. Recovering a plausible original from a divided manuscript tradition involves (1) positing an original which makes sense (2) explaining how manuscript readings differing from this original could have been derived from it. Solutions which fail these tests should be rejected. This does not, of course, mean that a solution that passes them must be right. I offer my suggestion. (1) (positing an original which makes sense) The original survives partly in Latin, partly in Greek: 21 Et cum audissent de eo exierunt detinere eum; dicebant enim quia "Adhaerent ei" ("" is my suggested retranslation from W's exertentai autou) (And when they {Jesus' opponents} heard about him they went out to seize him; they said: "They {the crowd} are attached to him"). (2) (explaining how manuscripts differing from this original could have been derived from it) The Greek translator translated cum audissent de eo exierunt detinere eum as akousantes par'autou exelthon kratesai auton (when they heard from him they went out to seize him). The sense is impossible. Jesus didn't say, in effect: "Come and get me". The translation of the Latin is also impossible. De eo means "about him", not "from him". "They heard from him" would be "audissent ab eo". Someone tried to improve the sense by adding oi, giving the accepted Greek text, but with W's exertentai (they are attached to him) for exeste (he is mad). Someone said: "Those around him can't have objected to Jesus because the crowds were attached to him; they would have welcomed that. Exertentai must be a corruption of something similar. I conjecture exeste (he is mad)".

Comment: If one is going to attempt Textual Criticism one has to supply far, far more detail than is present in the above answer to even begin to prove a point.

Answer (score 0):

I am not highly educated, but the last time I checked, the understanding of scripture has nothing to do with a person’s education.  In fact, I believe there is enough scripture to support that worldly knowledge often leads to the imaginations of men growing to become the enmity of God.  All truth and wisdom come from the Holy Spirit. That is why I read scripture, to seek Truth above all else!

Now I’m sure I am as guilty as anyone of doing this, but why do men work so hard to complicate the simple things of God? In my lifetime, the simple ways of God are the most beautiful and precious things in life.  In chapter 3 of Mark, he uses “family” when he means family and “scribes” when he means scribes, correct?  So why can’t “friends” just mean friends?   I have not read one commentary yet that states this is what is meant by Mark.  Mark has already told us the names of the brothers and sisters of Jesus, so is it so far-fetched to think that Mark would reference His childhood friends?  In 30 years of life, Jesus had to have childhood friends, right? True friends are few in life,  and friends will sit back and observe to a certain point before they intervene.  If you follow the written sequence of events in this manner, Mark’s description of events seems to represent a point of “change” in the ministry of Jesus. The fame of Jesus and the stories about Him had reached a point where:

1. His friends had seen enough to try to intervene to protect Him, thinking He might not be in His right mind
2. the scribes began to be more aggressive and “openly” challenge Him to go as far as to call Him Beelzebub
3. His entire family came to visit Him for some unspecified reason.

This is why Jesus said what He did about His family.  His ministry had reached a point where these things had to pass and were forever behind Him.  So Jesus now sends a clear message that serving the will of God was His first, second, and third priority! There was nobody on earth that would interfere with fulfilling His purpose!

I’m sure there is much more here, but to a common person, this sequence makes perfect sense.  His friends were dismissed with no further comment, His so-called “peers” who challenged Him were going to be embarrassed and put in their place, and His own family was set aside for one purpose!  In Mark,  it seems as though this is a point where His ministry reaches another level. Does an intense study of scripture support this?  I'm not exactly sure, but I know that immediately following this chapter, Jesus begins teaching in parables.  I’m just saying that “friends” can just mean “friends”. It works perfectly here and does not change the context or contradict the Truth of the Gospel of Jesus Christ. Until there is another **clear** explanation supported by scripture, I will believe that friends just means friends here.

Answer (score 0):

The text is surely confusing and enigmatic. I am aware that among the oldest manuscripts two traditions are following somewhat diverging paths, the one with "those with him" going out to take hold of something/somebody and the lesser-known version with scribes and others going out to do so. Impossible to ascertain which is voicing Mark's intentions correctly, but nowhere is said Jesus went out first, so it couldn't be him they intended to grab, he was at home all the time.

I would like to draw attention to what was **heard** because the preceding line of text might be a part of the solution:

Mark 3:20

> Then he/they went home, and once again a crowd gathered, so that they could not even eat bread.

Now, most commentators assume it is Jesus and the disciples who could not eat, but is that so? It seems more logical that the crowd was a hungry mob and the following action was a reaction to that, hearing about it "those with him", probably the disciples, going out to get hold of some bread because it was absent. In the miraculous feedings later on, they propose to go out to buy some, so completely in character. Now the word κρατησαι would be a bit strange, one would expect something like αγορασαι, but it's still possible.

My guess is no family was involved, an invention of the sandwich hungry, nor was Jesus mad, nowhere else εξεστη has that meaning, it simply says it (bread) is absent.